# Get First Span of a <div> using the data-id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, jquery-ui-draggable

I want to get the first span element of a div.

This is how i get the div DOM element.

```
helper: function(event,ui){
            var dataId = $(this).data('id');
            console.log($('[data-id="' + dataId + '"'));
        }
```

**NOTE** Im using [Draggable](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#visual-feedback) plugign from jquery-ui

The console.log prints correct the div element, but now i want to get the first span.

After a minor research i find that i cant use `.('span:first')`

But if i try

```
$('[data-id="' + dataId + '"').('span:first') //returns error.
```

**Returns error.**

> Unexpected token (

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is because it expects and method after `.` but finds `(` : `Unexpected token (`

You need to use `.find()` method on the object.

```
$('[data-id="' + dataId + '"]').find('span:first')
```

or

```
$('[data-id="' + dataId + '"] span:first')
```

or immediate `span` child

```
$('[data-id="' + dataId + '"] > span:first')
```

Comment: Hi I made it work like this. `$('[data-id="' + dataId + '"] span:first' );` is this a bad practice?

Comment: No. That is the best  one. I was just editing my answer with it.

Comment: Great i will accept this answer as soon i can =D (10 minutes)

Comment: Another good approach to find first level `span` would be to use `>`.